# Read SELECT'ed value and store it as an int in C

Tags: c, postgresql

It looks like I am unable to figure this one out.. I've been reading POSTGRESQL manual, but it does not go in depth on this specific problem, which is why Im asking for help here.
The main purpose is that I would like to turn my answer of query into a variable. I read that it requires to use PQgetvalue..? But I only have res and am unable to figure out what to put as the two other variables.. PQgetvalue should be utilised as following:

```
char *PQgetvalue(const PGresult *res,
                 int row_number,
                 int column_number);
```

This is my part of code, where I ask for query

```
char o[255];
    sprintf(o, "SELECT credits FROM subject WHERE id_subject = %d;", id_subject);
    printf("%s\n", o);
    res = PQexec(conn, o);
    CREDITS = PQgetvalue(res, , );
    printf("CREDITS= %d", CREDITS);
```

If I were to simply use that query in MyWebSQL, it gives me the proper answer, but I want to get the integer value of that query and store it in CREDITS.

I saw in a couple of code examples online that i and j are used as the two other variables, but it does not make sense to me, as I am not looping anything..?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for `PQgetvalue` the parameters are:

```
const PGresult *res
int row_number
int column_number
```

Further:

> Returns a single field value of one row of a PGresult. Row and column numbers start at 0.

So, if you are fetching the result of a query that is intended to return a single field, I imagine the value of `0` for both column and row number would be correct.

Comment: That seems like a good idea, but by writing 0's instead, I get a warning saying that "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"

Comment: Then you made some coding error. Edit the question and show a self-contained complete test case.